# Angularjs and SSO (SAML2)

Tags: angularjs, authentication, single-sign-on, pyramid, saml

I came across with this AngularJs thing, and I thing it is awesome, really solves many problems I confronted while working on my last WebApp with just a few lines of code.

Now, what I didn't find or was looking in bad places is the protection of AngularJs app with SSO (simpleSAMLphp Identity provider). How to deal with this?

What I am going to build will use Pyramid framework as a backend REST API, and AngularJs (I wish) for the frontend. But how to protect the app from unauthorized access, skipping the sso login. Any implementation example or lessons working on similar case would help (may be with php, ruby backends and SSO etc)

Comment: have you ever solved this? How did you end up doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't seem like pyramid has any direct support for SAML authetication. I suggest using a third party application for SAML. For example Shibboleth. The SAML communication is done on the server side so Angular wont need any integration.

Answer (score -3):

Google like 'Authentication in angular JS application' you can get lot to protect your angular app. To protect your REST API use Oauth whether its a php or ruby application.